# Hyperledger transaction type : Create transaction

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am currently reading the protocol spec of hyperledger/fabric. 
https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/protocol-spec.md

In section 3.1.2 Transaction Messages, it mentioned about an unimplemented type of transaction : Create transaction. But I don't understand the concept of this Create type, how is it different from the Invoke transaction type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this part of the protocol is under heavy refactoring.

I don't know if the Create transaction is still planned, but one Wiki page says that chaincode operations would change in the next architecture (even considering to remove the Deploy transaction) :

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/wiki/Fabric-Next#23-chaincode